# how to grab a fields data from inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to pull data from inside an iframe that links to http://www.w3schools.com/. I keep getting errors that won't allow me to pull out the data of any field or grab the entire page's html and put it into a variable.

I have already tried:

```
$('iframe').html();
```

I have also tried not loading it in an iframe so it could be accessed easier, but that also didn't work.

```
 $(function(){
          $("#includedContent").load("http://www.w3schools.com"); 
        });
```

Comment: what is the console error you are getting? You are loading from different domain than your page is on so the browser is bound to block such requests.

Answer (score 1):

To get contents from the body of an iframe, you should use:

```
$("iframe").contents().find('body').html();
```